# Why is `max-width` exclusive sometimes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create responsive layout with `max-width` media query. I want to style my `div` when screen width is `< 1280px`, so I use `max-width: 1279px`. But when setting screen width to exactly `1279px` styles won't apply. More than that, if I use `max-width: 1280px` they apply at `1280px` width.

Here's codepen with simplified version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeBKGO

```css
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .a { background: red; }
}
@media (max-width: 1279px) {
    .b { background: red; }
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  should be red at &le;1280
</div>
<div class='b'>
  should be red at &le;1279
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the expected behavior: moving from small to large, the first line turns white when the screen hits 1280, the second line turns white when the screen hits 1279. And this is in Firefox.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I'm getting the expected behaviour as well

Comment: Are you sure the first line turns red at `1280px` and second at `1279px`?

Comment: Same here: when I resize the window so that only the first line is red, it's exactly 1280px wide. Not gonna downvote someone who uses &le; correctly though.

Comment: @MrLister does the second line becomes red at `1279px` though?

Comment: Yes, any smaller or larger than 1280 and both lines are white or red. Wait a minute, do you have a high resolution screen where you can resize the browser window to 2559 hardware dots or 1279.5 logical pixels?

Comment: No. Just regular 1920x1080 screen

Comment: And you aren't zoomed in or out in the browser?

Comment: I'm using debugging tool in firefox/chrome, and I'm not zoomed

Comment: Oh, I had windows 10 setting to scale text to 125%. Setting it to 100% fixed the issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had windows 10 setting that would scale everything to 125%. Removing it fixed the issue

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much for mentioning this, I've been beating my head against the wall for quite a few hours because of this problem. Didn't know it was a freaking Windows 10 scaling issue. Thanks.